# Any good C++ finance (preferably high frequency trading) books people can recommend?

Tags: c++, caching, latency

was in a waterstones branch today and saw a C++ book relating to derivatives. Just wondered if there are any specific books relating to high frequency trading, from the infrastructure side?

I'm especially interested in latency issues and generally how to make a c++ (or java) trading platform.

I've seen CLI mentioned a few times, although i'm not sure if this is something i should learn too??

Comment: It's an arms race, nobody will give you any *practical* information in that regard.

Comment: These guys are entirely too busy sucking pennies out of my retirement fund every day to have the time.  They don't share their secrets either.

Comment: @Hans:  Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Nobody will share this information. But you can join to http://quant.stackexchange.com and ask this question. You may get some general answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The economics of publishing being what they are, I would be very surprised if there was a book published on such a narrow topic.

Answer (score 0):

None that I've ever seen.  If there were any, they would probably be terrible.

This is an area where the only way to learn how to do it is to get on to the battlefield.